# Angular - wait until DOM updated view for specific variable

Tags: angular

I am creating a chat application.  On changing a chat window, I want the scrollbar to navigate to the bottom in order to view the most recent messages immediately.  My code to do this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.updateMessageExchange.subscribe((interlocutor: MessageExchange) => {
        this.activeChatExchange = interlocutor; // this triggers a view change in the html
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('sleep');
            this.scrollToBottom();
        }, 100);

    });
}

private scrollToBottom(): void {
    this.chatBoard.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.chatBoard.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
}
```

corresponding relevant html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of activeChatExchange.messages">
```

This works, but I had to introduce a sleep to make it work. Without the sleep, the update of `scrollTop` happens too quick and the window on the next page will not be updated to scroll to the bottom.  This has nothing to do with the value of `scrollHeight` either.  If I set a really high static number like 999999 it will still not scroll to the bottom.

So the issue is that this solution is not very good.  A too high number for the sleep puts an artificial delay in my application, making it appear sluggish and too low a number may cause slow browsers to not be scrolled down after loading.

I would like to subscribe to when the DOM event change is finished, but only for a change in `activeChatExchange`.  How should I approach this?

Comment: You can add a setTimeout in scrollToBottom and fire a new scrollTop. You should do some checking to avoid an infinite loop, like checking if element.scroll is still changing, for example.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the solution, with help from [Angular - Wait for ngFor to update DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048559/angular-wait-for-ngfor-to-update-dom)

I'm not entirely sure if this qualifies as a proper solution, but setting the sleep to 0 apparently works because the function timeout starts counting after rendering, which is what I want.

So my code becomes

```
    this.updateMessageExchange.subscribe((interlocutor: MessageExchange) => {
        this.activeChatExchange = interlocutor;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.scrollToBottom();
        }, 0);
    });
```